# How to save the list item with document for anonymous user?

Tags: 2013, list, security

we have internet portal and anonymous users can view and visit the site and we have one page that anonymous user can fill the form and upload small size of documents less than 500 KB and it will save as list item in one of the list in site.

we facing one issue that when user trying to upload the document it asking authentication and our load balance restricting this and also we can not give the read/write permissions to anonymous user , there is any way to save the list item for anonymous user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to give *write* permissions to anonymous users for a given list is to use PowerShell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://SiteAddress
$list = $web.Lists["List Name"]
if(-Not($list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments))
{
    $list.BreakRoleInheritance($true)
}
$list.AnonymousPermMask64 = "AddListItems" # or anything else you want, like "Open, ViewListItems, AddListItems"...
$list.Update()
```